# Additional mime types in Focus Lab config - how to add?

Tags: focus-lab-master-config, bootstrap

Is it possible to add additional mime types to the $mimes array (/system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php) from the config.master.php when using the Focus Lab config setup?

I really don't want to start changing files in the expressionengine directory to have it potentially be skipped when upgrading EE core software. Need to add in mime types for kml/kmz files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Focus Lab config will only override variables in config.php and database.php by default. You could add an additional `require xxx/config.master.php` to mimes.php if you wanted to, but since that requires editing the file anyway, and it unnecessarily complicates things, you're better off just adding the new mime types directly.

```
// Custom mime types
'kml'   =>  'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml',
'kmz'   =>  'application/vnd.google-earth.kmz'
```

I'd suggest also submitting a support request/bug report/email to EL requesting that those mime types are included in future releases.

Comment: Pretty much what I do as well. Since that file is just a big old array, I keep a version  of it in a repo and I update it every time I encounter a mime type that's not in there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, only guessing:

```
$env_config['mimes'] = array(
    'kml' => 'whatever'
);
```

Comment: I'd need to check and see if doing that adds to the existing array, or replaces it.